# SQLite3::query syntax error

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this php code to get data from database

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDb();

if (isset($_POST['limit']) && isset($_POST['start'])) {

$start = $_POST["start"];
$limit = $_POST["limit"];

$query =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY quiz_id DESC '$start', '$limit';
EOF;

$result = $db->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
  echo 'div class="quesbox">
  <div class="questitle">
      <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="quesanswer">'.$row["answer"].'</div>
    <div class="quesdatetime"><img src="images/questime.png" alt="export question">'.$row["date"].'</div>
  </div>';
}

}
?>
```

But each time i run this block of code i get these errors

```
Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "'0'": syntax error in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\searchfetch.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\searchfetch.php on line 16
```

I have tried all the possible ways i know to fix the issue by editing the `query` statement but to no avail. Please where is the issue from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do a `echo $query;`. Obviously there is something wrong with the query.

Comment: This is the `echo` result `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY quiz_id DESC '0', '7';` I am trying to seat a limit from which data would be gotten from the database of wihich 7 is the limit

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `LIMIT`

```
$query =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY quiz_id DESC LIMIT '$start', '$limit';
EOF;
```